# Why does [-1:-1:-1] not work for reversing a string?

Tags: python, string, slice

Maybe someone can explain why a particular slice operation to reverse
a string doesn't work. There must be something about slices I don't
understand. Basic operation: s[start:end:step]

Given

```
s='abcd'
```

to reverse this string I can do using default values

```
s[::-1]
```

or

```
s[-1::-1]
```

Those are fine, but why doesn't

```
s[-1:-1:-1]
```

work and give me the whole string reversed? It should start at with
the last character in the string at (-1), and the stepsize is -1. It should run
down to one before -1 i.e., index 0. Instead I get ''.

```
for i in xrange(3, -2, -1):
    print 's[-1:%d:-1] => ' %i,
    print s[-1:i:-1]
```

yields:

```
s[-1:3:-1] =>     # didn't expect any output
s[-1:2:-1] =>  d
s[-1:1:-1] =>  dc
s[-1:0:-1] =>  dcb
s[-1:-1:-1] =>    # shouldn't this be 'dcba'?
```

what am I missing here?

(I did see a lot of posting on reversing strings, but if this particular item was explained somewhere I missed it)

Comment: If your slice starts and ends at the same index, how could it ever be anything other than empty?

Comment: What @FatalError said. By the way, "one before -1" would not be index 0, it would be -2. Arithmetically, 0 is one after -1.

Comment: Yes you can construct a string slice which tries to downcount across 0 and below. But it acts weird: `s[2:-2:-1]` strangely is empty, but `s[-2:2:-1]` seems to work even though at first glance it shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s[-1:-1:-1]
```

Doesn't work for the same reason that

```
s[0:0]
```

doesn't give you 'abcd'.

When you slice, you are referring to the space *between* two elements, not the location of those elements.  So you're asking for the space between -1 and -1, which is ''.

Comment: thanks .. I was focused too much on the index values themselves, rather than the semantics of "slice" .. ie the space between .. very helpful

Answer (score 3):

In

```
>>> s[-1:-1:-1]
>>> ''
```

The `start` and `end` are both `-1` so they are the same. A slice takes each element in the array from the `start` to the `end` as it increases by the `step` each time. If it has already reached the `end` then the slice is finished... therefore it returns `''`.

Try:

```
>>> s[1:1:1]
>>> ''
```

That might help this make more sense as it is almost the same thing, but positive.

Comment: thanks .. you are right, looking at it with all positive index values does make it clear. Since my other examples (in the loop) worked as I expected, I wrongly assumed my conclusion would be correct too.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, negative and non-negative indices are two separate classes:

- non-negative indices start from the beginning;
- negative indices start from the end.

It seems pretty logical to me that slicing is defined such that the latter never overflow into the former, as you seem to be expecting when you say:

> It should run down to one before -1 i.e., index 0

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the whole point of slicing

`[start:end:stride]` is what a slice operator would look like

if stride is negative, then definitely your start should be greater than end as you are moving from high to low. All your examples which fails violates that.

You should definitely start reading [Extended Slicing](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

Comment: I have, but I probably could benefit from reviewing it - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect `-1` to mean *both* the final item in the string *and* the "item before" the first item in the string. That would be inconsistent.

Perhaps you're imagining that Python is treating a string as a loop, and thinking of `-1` as if it were simultaneously the "item before" `0` and the last item in the string. But that's not the case. For example, if that were the case, then this would hold:

```
'abcd'[-2:-1:-1] == 'cbad'
```

But it doesn't. The result is simply the empty string.

```
>>> 'abcd'[-2:-1:-1] 
''
```

The correct interpretation of negative indices in string slicing is as reverse indexing from the end of the string, not as cyclical indexing from `0`.

As further food for thought, consider the following:

```
a = 'abcd'
a[-1:-(len(a) + 0):-1] == 'dcb'
a[-1:-(len(a) + 1):-1] == 'dcba'
a[-1:-(len(a) + 2):-1] == 'dcba'
```

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of unfortunate, isn't it? Here's an awkward workaround.

```
for i in range(3, -2, -1):
    j = i if i != -1 else None
    print 's[-1:%s:-1] => ' % str(j),
    print s[-1:j:-1]

s[-1:3:-1] =>  
s[-1:2:-1] =>  d
s[-1:1:-1] =>  dc
s[-1:0:-1] =>  dcb
s[-1:None:-1] =>  dcba
```

Here's a variation on the same thing. I'm not sure if it's any less awkward.

```
for i in range(3, -1, -1) + [None]:
    print 's[-1:%s:-1] => ' % str(i),
    print s[-1:i:-1]

s[-1:3:-1] =>  
s[-1:2:-1] =>  d
s[-1:1:-1] =>  dc
s[-1:0:-1] =>  dcb
s[-1:None:-1] =>  dcba
```